# Can we create a default template for new Wiki pages in Sharepoint Foundation 2013?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, wiki, template

I'm wandering if it's possible to create a template to use as default new Wiki pages ?
As I've got SP Foundation 2013 version, I can't use the Design Manager.

Because we got page layout to respect when creating Wiki pages, and I can't come up with the idea of copy/paste the whole content of a default page each time I want to create a new Wiki page.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you very much in advance.
Cheers,

EDIT : I found this link : http://www.mssharepointtips.com/tip.asp?id=1072&page=2

Basically, it was a javascript code designed to create Wiki pages from a template on SharePoint 2010 and don't seems to work on 2013 anymore ... trying to adapt the code.
thanks for any other hints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I finally succeeded to create a solution answering to my needs.
I'll try to summarize it :

I built a Javascript script that use the 3 main SharePoint JS libraries : ECMA scripting.
I found pretty the same thing that I've wanted to make and I adapted it, and added a few things : http://www.sharepointdevelopment.me/2011/05/working-with-files-in-sharepoint-from-ecma-script/

Then, I've created a code snippet WebPart into an .aspx page of my SharePoint :

1. Created a formulary inside with an input, to type the page name, radio buttons, to choose the Wiki where I want to create the page, and then a dropdown list to select the template I want to use.
2. Linked the form with my Js function.
3. Added a link generated at the end to access directly the page just created.

Comment: I also have similar requirement. Can you please me in creating a template.?